# Не добавляет данные в базу данных mySQL. ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'adad' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Хочу через пост запрос добавить в таблицу несколько новых полей которые ввел пользователь.

```
app.post('/moderator', function(request, response) {
    if (!request.body) return sendStatus(400);
    connection.query('INSERT INTO news(`title`, `text`) VALUES(' + request.body.title + ',' + request.body.text + ')', function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    response.redirect('/moderator');
    response.end();
});
```

Но в итоге получаю данную ошибку:

```
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'фвфвфв' in 'field list'
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:200:25)
    at /media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/server.js:48:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/media/selin/Data/Documents/WORK/My Projects/Web Developing/GitHub/IgorZaviryukhaA2Lab/lesson_5/5-2_News/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

В консоль данные выводятся, имена ячеек правильные, и атрибуты name также совпадают.

```
<form id="add_post" class="d-flex justify-content-between" method="post">
                        <div class="add-post__left">
                            <h3>Add new post</h3>
                            <div class="add-post__form-set">
                                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
                                <textarea name="text" placeholder="Text"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-post__right">
                            <button type="submit">Post</button>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Чему в этот момент равны `request.body.title` и `request.body.text`? Выглядит очень похоже на попытку SQL-инъекции.

Comment: @Yaant разве они не равны данным из текстовых полей с именем title и text?

Comment: @Yaant при выводе в консоль выводит то что ввел пользователь с клавиатуры в форму, но не добавляет в БД

Comment: Вот я и спрашиваю, что конкретно ввел пользователь, в момент возникновения ошибки? Потому что запрос ```INSERT INTO news(`title`, `text`) VALUES('12345','67890')``` никак не может вызвать сообщение об ошибке «Unknown column 'фвфвфв' in 'field list'».

Comment: @Yaant без разницы что, текст и числа, все равно ошибка(

Comment: То есть вводите `abcd`, а получаете ошибку про `column 'фвфвфв'`? Не верю.

Comment: @Yaant да нет..ну ввожу например "adad" = column "adad"

Comment: Выведите еще окончательный текст запроса, перед его выполнением. То есть типа `let sql = 'INSERT INTO ...', console.log(sql); connection.query(sql, ...)`. Потому что все равно что-то очень странное происходит.

Comment: @Yaant ну вот теперь так пишет Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Lorem Ipsum???,\u0444\u0432\u0444\u0432\u0444\u0432\u0444\u0432\u0444\u0432\u04442\u04434234\u0443214\u044323)' at line 1

Comment: @Yaant let sql = 'INSERT INTO news(`title`, `text`) VALUES(' + request.body.title + ',' + request.body.text + ')';

Comment: ... ... ... Я спрашиваю, чему равно значение `sql` в этот момент? Впрочем, уже не надо. Значения в VALUES надо заключать в кавычки.

Comment: В тексте ФОРМИРУЕМОГО запроса должны быть кавычки вокруг вставляемых литералов. Сейчас их нет. Должно быть нечто типа `connection.query('INSERT INTO news(`title`, `text`) VALUES(\'' + request.body.title + '\',\'' + request.body.text + '\')', function(err, result)`